# Erro no sequelize ao realizar registro no BD [Model.hasMany called with something that's not a subclass of Sequelize.Model]

Tags: javascript, node.js, postgresql, modelo-relacional, sequelize-js

Estou fazendo um projeto node, utilizando o sequelize como ORM. Tenho 4 tabelas se relacionando [Fator, Sub_fator, Obs_fator, Metas], quando vou executar o create da esse erro:
**Error: Fator.hasMany called with something that's not a subclass of Sequelize.Model**

**Observações:**

> banco: postgresql
>
> Um obs_fator só pode estar relacionado a um fator;
>
> Um sub_fator tem um fator;
>
> Um fator pode estar relacionado a vários sub_fatores;
>
> Uma meta se relaciona a um sub_fator;

model Fator

```js
    'use strict';

    module.exports = (sequelize, DataTypes) => {
      const Fator = sequelize.define('Fator', {
        descricao: DataTypes.STRING
      }, {});
      Fator.associate = function(models) {
        this.belongsTo(models.Obs_fator, {
          as: 'obs_Fatores'
        });
        this.hasMany(models.Sub_fator, {
          foreignKey: 'id',
          as: 'Fatores'
        })
      };
      return Fator;
    };
```

model Sub_fator

```js
    'use strict';
    const Metas = require('./metas');

    module.exports = (sequelize, DataTypes) => {
      const Sub_Fator = sequelize.define('Sub_Fator', {
        fatorId: DataTypes.INTEGER,
        descricao: DataTypes.STRING
      }, {});
      Sub_Fator.associate = function(models) {
        Sub_Fator.belongsTo(models.Fator, {
          foreignKey: 'fatorId',
          as: 'Fator'
        });
        Sub_Fator.hasMany(Metas);
      };
      return Sub_Fator;
    };
```

model obs_fator

```js
    'use strict';
    module.exports = (sequelize, DataTypes) => {
      const Obs_fator = sequelize.define('Obs_fator', {
        alunoId: DataTypes.INTEGER,
        fatoId: DataTypes.INTEGER,
        descricao: DataTypes.STRING,
        value: DataTypes.INTEGER
      }, {});
      Obs_fator.associate = function(models) {
        Obs_fator.belongsTo(models.Fator, {
          foreignKey:'fatoId', as:'fator'
        })
      };
      return Obs_fator;
    };
```

model Metas

```js
    'use strict';
    module.exports = (sequelize, DataTypes) => {
      const Metas = sequelize.define('Metas', {
        sub_fatorId: DataTypes.INTEGER,
        alunoId: DataTypes.INTEGER,
        descricao: DataTypes.STRING,
        value: DataTypes.INTEGER
      }, {});
      Metas.associate = function(models) {
        Metas.belongsTo(models.Sub_fator, {
          foreignKey: 'sub_fatorId', as: 'sub_fator'
        })
      };
      return Metas;
    };
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seu problema ocorre por conta de um erro de digitação.

No **Model Fator**, use `this.hasMany(models.Sub_Fator, {` ao invés de `this.hasMany(models.Sub_fator, {`. Ênfase em **Sub_Fator** ao invés de **Sub_fator**.

Isso ocorre porque no **Model Sub_Fator** você está exportando definindo como:

```
  const Sub_Fator = sequelize.define('Sub_Fator', {
```

(Com o F maiúsculo).

Outra opção para a correção seria renomear no **Model Sub_Fator** para o F minúsculo.